# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Currently I'm learning Obj-C for Mac developing, with Cocoa. I made a simple file browser with an inspector, to see a file's icon an some info. So far, so good. Now I made it document based, so I could have more than one open windows.

To tell the inspector which file it should inspect, I use the `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification`. Works fine for switching between windows, but it gives an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I close all windows and then open a new one.

This is the method that handles the notification:

```
- (void)windowChanged: (NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    BrowserWindow *doc = [[window windowController] document];

    if (currentDocument != doc) {

        [currentDocument.arrayController removeObserver: self
                                             forKeyPath: @"selectionIndex"];

        [icon setImage:nil];
        [size setStringValue:@"-"];
        [owner setStringValue:@"-"];
        [filename setStringValue:@"(none selected)"];

        [doc.arrayController addObserver: self
                              forKeyPath: @"selectionIndex"
                                 options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                                 context: NULL];
        currentDocument = doc;
    }
}
```

The error occurs where it calls `removeObserver:forkeyPath:` on the `currentDocument.arrayController`. It kinda makes sense, it tries to remove the observer for something that doesn't exist anymore, 'cause the window is closed. But how to fix it? I just can't think of anything else..

Could someone point me in the right directions?

I appreciate the help! :)

--

It's getting weirder.. Just checked the example that was downloadable from the website of the book I've got, and they're using the same approach, but it works all fine. Can't find any differences, it's driving me crazy.

--

Solved! More details later.

Comment: Of which class is this a method?

Comment: Did you `retain` currentDocument anywhere?  (I'm guessing not.)

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis It's a method of the `InspectorController`.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: I did not `retain` it. I just placed a `NSLog` with a `retainCount` before the removeObserver, just before it goes wrong, it shows this: `2011-09-05 00:43:06.015 FileBrowser1[17664:707] Cannot remove an observer <InspectorController 0x10014b730> for the key path "selectionIndex" from <NSView 0x10049a1e0> because it is not registered as an observer.`

Comment: The message above contains the NSLog, which is empty.. Not 0 or something, just nothing. Before it just showed numeric values.

Comment: When you see an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash, it usually means you need to run your app under Instruments using the Zombies template. This will tell you (1) exactly when you try to talk to an object that has been deallocated, (2) what object it was, (3) what message you (or something else) tried to send to it, and (4) the entire history of that object from allocation through deallocation all the way to the crash.

Comment: Also: You named your document class “BrowserWindow”? That suggests that it is a window (NSWindow), not a document (NSDocument). For your purpose, I suggest something very general: FileDocument, or ItemDocument, or even just Document.

Comment: Since you don't `retain` currentDocument, the object goes "poof" as soon as it closes.  If you retain it, it will hang around such that removeObserver will work.  (Of course, if you retain it you must implement proper protocols to cause it to be `release`d at an appropriate time, but I assume you're entirely familiar with the memory management protocols in Objective-C, as that is a prerequisite for even beginning to code in it.)

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I agree that BrowserWindow isn't the clearest name, gonna keep that in mind. I tried Instruments, but I don't know where to look. I'll gonna dig into that soon. :)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: I used the code that Rudy Velthuis posted, which retains the `currentDocument`. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not surprised, since you likely have multiple bugs.  I suggest that you spend a few hours researching how memory management works in Objective-C.

Comment: And poking around in Instruments. When you run your app under the Zombies template, you'll get a flag in the timeline when you try to send a message to an object that has been deallocated (which will have become a zombie). Click on the button in that flag to go to the history of the object. Then, look at all of the events in the history to see which release should not be there, or should be balanced by a retain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To tell the inspector which file it should inspect, I use the `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification`. Works fine for switching between windows, but it gives an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I close all windows and then open a new one.

This is part of the problem right there. When the last window closes, no window will become main. So, you also need to handle the case where a window *resigns* main, as happens when it closes (and when another window becomes main).

Your inspector probably should both retain the document and switch documents after a delay, using a timer (whose fire date you postpone every time another did become/resign main notification comes in) or delayed perform (which you cancel and re-perform every time). When the timer/perform fires, find out what document, if any, is the active document, and update the inspector accordingly.

Also note that you can have no active document (no document window is the main window) even when there are documents open. The About panel and your Preferences panel are two good ways to achieve (and test) this.

Comment: What's the difference between opening a new window while no others are open, in which case there's no `currentWindow`, and when you close the active window and another becomes active. In the last case, there also isn't an main window when the other is becoming main?

Comment: @GuidoH: Yes there is. The window that becomes active is the one that is becoming main—that's what “main window” means in Cocoa.

Comment: My comment was a bit weird, but the old window - that I close - that one isn't there when the other one becomes 'main window'?

Comment: @GuidoH: When you close the window that is the main window, it resigns main window. If there are any other windows, one of them will become the main window (and you will see the appearance of its frame change to reflect this). If the window you closed was your last window (i.e., you have no other open windows), then no window becomes the main window. That's why you need to handle both resign-main-window and become-main-window.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Gonna look into that and gonna think about how to implement your solution. It makes sense to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Daniel is probably right: You probably don't retain currentDocument. Make currentDocument a property:

```
@property (retain) BrowserWindow *currentDocument;
```

And synthesize it in the implementation section:

```
@synthesize currentDocument;
```

And change your code to:

```
- (void) windowChanged: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    BrowserWindow *doc = [[window windowController] document];

    if (self.currentDocument != doc) 
    {
        [self.currentDocument.arrayController removeObserver: self
                                                  forKeyPath: @"selectionIndex"];

        [icon setImage: nil];
        [size setStringValue: @"-"];
        [owner setStringValue: @"-"];
        [filename setStringValue: @"(none selected)"];

        [doc.arrayController addObserver: self
                              forKeyPath: @"selectionIndex"
                                 options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                                 context: NULL];
        self.currentDocument = doc;
    }
}
```

You might want to do the same for *icon*, *size*, *owner* and *filename*.

And heed the warning of the message: you probably don't register self as observer to start with.

Comment: It looks like something changed, but it's not working yet. Sometimes I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, other times the windows just open and hangs, with the titlebar like it's inactive. Still says: `2011-09-05 00:52:35.074 FileBrowser1[17849:707] Cannot remove an observer <InspectorController 0x10043ee30> for the key path "selectionIndex" from <NSWindow 0x100165080> because it is not registered as an observer.`. Which actually makes sense to me.. When closing a window, doesn't that automatically get rid of the observer? `Icon`, `size`, `owner` and `filename` are IBOutlets, does they need it as well?

Comment: @GuidoH: No, an object being deallocated while something is still observing it will get you a different warning, saying basically what I just said. Something is trying to remove the observer, possibly you, but you haven't added it yet.

Comment: arrayController certainly __isn't__ a window, it's just an `NSArrayController`. The only place that the InspectorController is added as an Observer is in the code in my post. So the first time that it's registered is when the first window opens.

Comment: If they are IBOutlets, no need to retain. But the message seems to say that you are trying to remove an InspectroController as an observer from an NSWindow. Is arrayController a window? And where did you register your InspectorController as observer for the first time?

Comment: @GuidoH: but the message says you are trying to remove an observer from an NSWindow, not from an NSArrayController. That is suspicious.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Pretty strange, 'cause when it first runs, there's no current document and he's still trying to remove the observer. Oh, now it just gives the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` again.. I just don't get it, error messages seems randomly switching between the observer error and the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: @Rudy: Yes, it's suspicious and pretty strange. But the code given contains the only `removeObserver` I got in here. But some times it just stops and gives the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: If the currentDocument is nil, that's OK. If it is the address of a dealloced item, you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, unless that address was reused for, say, an NSWindow, which would give you the message you get. ISTM that currentDocument is released too soon.

Comment: You try to remove an observer from an array controller, but the message says it is from a window. See my comment above. currentDocument is probably invalid.

Comment: That makes sense, but how is it released? Does it get released when I close the window?

Comment: @GuidoH: That depends on whether you have that option turned on. Examine your window in IB and see whether “release when closed” is on.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I knew that there was an option like that, so that was one of the first things I checked. Unfortunately that wasn't it, was already turned off.